# Java; Component.enableEvents ( ... ) does not work?

Tags: java, swing, events, components

Recently, I discovered the Component.enableEvents ( ... ) method. The way that I would imagine that it would work would be that `Component.enableEvents ( MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED )` would only alert me if that specific event happened. However, it does not work like that, or I just cannot figure it out.

Right now, I have this code:

```
frame.enableEvents(FocusEvent.FOCUS_GAINED | FocusEvent.FOCUS_LOST | ComponentEvent.COMPONENT_RESIZED);
```

But I still find that I get component moved events, component hidden, etc.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JavaDoc for that method:

> This method only needs to be invoked by subclasses of Component which desire to have the specified event types delivered to processEvent regardless of whether or not a listener is registered.

This says nothing about filtering out event types that are not named.